# How to call connect() method of weblogic in python which is called inside a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, python, weblogic

The requirement is to call the weblogic function:

```
connect([username, password], [url], [adminServerName])
```

inside a **python file** which is again called inside a **shellscript** as follows:

Inside shell script:

```
python myweblogiccall.py
```

I am getting an exception like

> unknown name connect

when called inside the python file

Comment: Do you not get this exception when you call it another way? Could you post a working example of what myweblogiccall.py is supposed to do?

Comment: myweblogiccall.py is suppose to contain: connect([myuser, myuser123], 't3://localhost:7001')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although WLST scripts have py or jy extension they are different than Python scripts in the way they function. Any WLST script needs an environment to be setup before coming up into action. There are 2 ways you can run your WLST scripts. I am assuming that you only need help to run WLST and a working WLST script is handy already.

1. Source setDomainEnv.sh and call WLST script as below.

   ```
   source <Domain_HOME>/bin/setDomainEnv.sh
   java weblogic.WLST <Script_HOME>/script.py
   ```
2. Run the WLST script through wlst.sh

   ```
   ./<Oracle_HOME>/Oracle_common/bin/wlst.sh <Script_HOME>/script.py
   ```

Comment: There is a requirement to call importMetadata(application=...) also after connect. Thats why i need to run my own python file to execute in shellscript.

Comment: Put all your steps in a single py file. and follow above approach to execute. It should work unless your python script has issues.